# Condition for a vector field to admit a potential

Tags: optimization, game-theory, multivariable-calculus

Let $C:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$ a smooth vector field.
Are there known conditions on its Jacobian that provide the existence of a potential function $W:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ such that $\nabla W = C$ ?

Comment: $\partial_i C_j=\partial_j C_i$ for all $i,j=1,2,\ldots n$ is the condition (which amounts to  requiring that $\partial_i\partial_jW=\partial_j\partial_iW$)

Comment: By Poincare' lemma, a vector field in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is conservative if and only if it is closed (i.e., irrotational).